# Remove item from groovy list

Tags: collections, groovy

I am trying to remove an item from groovy list. I've tried following:

```
    List<User>  availableUsers = []

    availableUsers = workers

    for (int i = 0; i < availableUsers.size(); i++) {
        if (availableUsers[i].equals(user)){
            availableUsers.drop(i)
            break
        }
    }
```

I've also tried:

```
availableUsers.remove(user)
```

In both cases the list gets emptied. Does anyone have any idea what's going on?

Comment: drop is not right: http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html#drop(int)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fildor is right, but if you only want ot remove the first occurence of `user` in your list (minus will remove all occurrences), you will probably need something like:

```
list = list.indexOf( user ).with { idx ->
  if( idx > -1 ) {
    new ArrayList( list ).with { a ->
      a.remove( idx )
      a
    }
  }
  else list
}
```

Answer (score 17):

Have you tried

```
availableUsers - user
```

?

Docu: http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html#minus(java.lang.Object)
Haven't got much experience with groovy myself, but that's what I would try.

Comment: Minus operator for list is NOT a best choice when you are dealing with  large lists and their data is complicated.
Refer this : http://rewoo.wordpress.com/2012/11/19/the-weak-performance-of-the-groovy-minus-operator/

Comment: @PhatH.VU 1. Make it run, 2. make it run correctly, 3. make it run fast. In exactly that order :D But of course, you are right.

Answer (score 13):

As mentioned above, the answer depends on whether you wish to remove all occurrences of an item...

```
myList = ['a','b','c', 'c']
myList -= 'c'
assert myList == ['a','b']
```

...or just the first instance.

```
myList = ['a','b','c', 'c']
myList.remove(myList.indexOf('c'))
assert myList == ['a','b','c']
```

I'm still new to Groovy myself, but one of the underlying principles is that it almost always has a way of making common tasks trivial one-liners.  Adding or removing items from a collection would certainly qualify.

Answer (score 1):

I had a related requirement but wanted to remove more than one items knowing their index position. It was **not easy to do in a loop** as after removing the first item, the index position of the remaining ones changes. It seemed easy to first create a list with items to be removed and then use the collections minus operation to remove them from the target list. Here is an example:

```
myList=['a','b','c','d']
remove=[0,1,2] //index list of list elements  to remove
removeList=myList[remove]
println removeList
assert ['d']== myList.minus(removeList)
```

LIMITATION:if the value at index is present multiple times in target list, ALL instances are removed.

So, if

```
myList=['a','b','c','d','a','e']
remove=[0,1,2]
removeList=myList[remove]
assert myList.minus(removeList)== ['d','e']
```

the result will be d,e